# How can I add data from an Item into a ListView without triggering an InvalidOperationException?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm

I have a ListView:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ModuleList}">
    <!--<DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,0,0,0">
            <Image Source="{Binding ModuleImage}" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ModuleName}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>-->
</ListView>
```

This ListView is bound to the ModuleList:

```
public List<Module> ModuleList
{
    get => modulList;
    set
    {
        modulList = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

The list stores objects of the type `Module`, a class that stores a string `Name`, an Image `ModuleImage` and a string `ModuleType`:

```
public class Module
{
    public Image ModuleImage { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ModuleType { get; set; }
}
```

and last, I have another class `ModuleLoader` that creates the Module-Objects for me. The Modules are zip-files that are named like the module (For example `Input.zip`). In there I have an image and a json, where Name and ModuleType are stored. The `ModuleLoader` then unzips the modules, creates a `Module` with the json and adds the Image path to that object.

The `ModuleList` gets filled like this:

```
//Unzips all modules into the Temp-Folder
modulLoader.LoadAllModules();

//Creates the object of type Module and adds the image path
modulList = modulLoader.GetAllModules();
```

Now when I uncomment the middle part of my Xaml, I get the exception after the ModuleList got created completely (Constructor is at its end)

```
Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead
```

when

```
get => modulList;
```

gets called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write the ListView like this, you are missing the `ListView.ItemTemplate`:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ModuleList}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,0,0,0">
                <Image Source="{Binding ModuleImage}" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ModuleName}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Without the item template there is no way to determine that the following XAML is a layout to follow.